# Apple Music / iTunes: Cannot add track to playlist when iPhone connected via wifi

Tags: itunes, wifi, music, playlist

Following occurs when using Apple Music / itunes: 
I'm in itunes, listening to some music from an Apple Music Playlist. I am also connected to a wifi network, the same network that my iPhone is on.

When I like a track I want to add it to one of my own playlists so I click on the three dots, select 'add to playlist', select the correct playlist and all is well.

However, when itunes shows the little phone icon in the icon bar (indicating my iPhone was detected in the same wifi and wifi sync is available, although I am not actually syncing anything) the option to add a song to a playlist disappears. It is no longer available when I click the three dots next to a song. As soon as I eject the iPhone, the option is available once more.

What is happening here (why does add to playlist disappear), and how can I keep adding music to a playlist even when the iPhone is connected via wifi sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been bugging me so much, it seemed so random but yes it definitely disappears the moment you plug in the iPhone, then appears again the moment you take it out.

I assume this is a bug and will be fixed soon, but here are a couple workarounds:

1. As you say, eject the iPhone either by physically disconnecting, or clicking the eject icon.
2. You can click "Add to My Music", then go to your library, find the relevant song, and drag/drop into a playlist. It works, but it's not much fun.

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer: by now I'm also convinced it is a bug and there is no real solution except an update from Apple.